# Await FinishedLoading() in Xamarin.Forms iOS

Tags: c#, ios, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have an issue, where app tries to run my login page before Apple's FinishedLoading method is done in my Xamarin.Forms app. That results in user being prompted to allow notifications, asked for internet access, and asked to log in at the same time. Not cool. How do I go about awaiting FinishedLoading() from AppDelegate?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This seems impossible because this is the entry point to the program.Why don't you do that in MainPage ?

Comment: Hm... could I bother you to walk me through what you mean? So the app starts in my AppleDelegate, correct? now that leads to a page where I check user's login token data and then I put the user in the dashboard. The flow works very well after I log in once, but when the app is installed it asks for permission to get push notifications and internet access. That causes the pop up that appears at the end of AppleDelegate method, right before launching App.cs. Now the issue is that it does not stop the thread waiting for user to allow/block notifications, so the login starts too. Any ideas?